# in TowerDefence Code,for spawning enemies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to spawn multiple enemies in the same enemy wave,maybe some one can help...in new to C#.

thats the code in using now:

```
public class WaveSpawner_2 : MonoBehaviour
{

public static int EnemiesAlive = 0;

 public Wave2[] waves;
 public Transform spawnPoint;
 public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;

[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI waveCountDownText;

public GameManager gameManager;

       float countDown = 2f;
        
        int waveIndex = 0;

 void Start() 
 {
   EnemiesAlive = 0;  
 }

 private void Update() 
 {
    
    if(EnemiesAlive > 0)
    {
      return;
    }
    
    if (waveIndex == waves.Length)
        {
       gameManager.WinLevel();
         this.enabled = false;
        }
            
    if(countDown <= 0f)
    {
       StartCoroutine(SpawnWave());
       countDown = timeBetweenWaves;
       return;
    }
    
    countDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    countDown = Mathf.Clamp(countDown, 0f, Mathf.Infinity);
    waveCountDownText.text = string.Format("{0:00.00}", countDown);
  }
 
   IEnumerator SpawnWave ()
    {
        PlayerStats.Rounds++;
      Wave2 wave = waves[waveIndex];
      EnemiesAlive = wave.count;
        for (int i = 0; i < wave.count; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy(wave.enemy);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / wave.rate);
        }
        waveIndex++;
    }   
    void SpawnEnemy(GameObject enemy)
    {
       Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
       EnemiesAlive++;
    }
  

}
```

and thats the second class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Wave2
{
  [Header("DeafultEnemy")]
  public GameObject enemy;
  public int count;
  public float rate;

  
}
```

ive been looking 2 days for the solution but coiuldnt find one..im new to c# so maybe i did found it but didnt understand it...trying my luck here, thanks.

Comment: You could change `enemy` in `Wave2` to be an array of enemy prefabs.   Then in your spawn wave function, choose a prefab and spawn it.  You could extend this thinking further where instead of enemy prefabs, its a class array with additional variables and the prefab.

Comment: maybe you could show me how to wright it....im pretty new to C# and didnt realy got a hold on the right way to use arrays,lists,etc.....thanks

Comment: ok so i did what you told ne to,but still its the same problem xD....in 1 wave i san only spawn 1 game object enemy[1] or[2] etc.......what i want to do is that in 1 wave i will be able to spawn multiple game objects enemy, and it will be the same wave....so like in wave 1 i will spawn 3(for example) diferet game objects and after i kill them all the wave 2 begins and in wave 2 i will spawn 5 (for example) diferent game objects enemy...and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this goal is to change the GameObject enemy inside of Wave2 to an array.

```
[Serializable]
public class WaveData
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;
    public int count;
    public float rate;
}
```

Then inside of SpawnWave, you can use the prefabs array to get a random prefab, alternate between prefabs, or some other picking algorithm.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wave.count; i++)
{
    // Getting a random enemy
    var enemyToSpawn = wave.prefabs[Random.Range(0, wave.prefabs.Length)];
    SpawnEnemy(enemyToSpawn);
}
```